# Translated publications of Boltzmann

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, specific-reference

I have been looking for Boltzmann's papers (in english) and had no luck. Anyone knows if they were translated at the first place, and if yes where to find them?

Comment: https://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/files/uploads/Boltzmann.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Four of Boltzmann's prominent papers are translated into English on pages

262. Ludwig Boltzmann: Further Studies on the Thermal Equilibrium of Gas Molecules (from *Sitzungsberichte der kaiserlichen Akademie der Wissenschaften*, Vienna, 1872)

&

362. Ludwig Boltzmann: On the Relation of a General Mechanical Theorem to the Second Law of Thermodynamics (from *Sitzungsberichte der kaiserlichen Akademie der Wissenschaften*, Vienna, 1877)

&

392. Ludwig Boltzmann; [Reply to Zermelo's Remarks on the Theory of Heat](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/boltzmann/zermelo.html) (from *Annalen der Physik*, 1896)

&

412. Ludwig Boltzmann: On Zermelo's Paper "On the Mechanical Explanation of Irreversible Processes" (from *Annalen der Physik*, 1897)

of

- Brush, Stephen G, and Nancy S Hall. *[The Kinetic Theory of Gases: An Anthology of Classic Papers with Historical Commentary](https://site.ebrary.com/id/10255810)*. London; River Edge, NJ: Imperial College Press ; Distributed by World Scientific Pub., 2003.

Comment: If anyone is interested, some of Brush's translations are available online. For example: the [response to Zermelo](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/boltzmann/zermelo.html).